# How to Create 3 elements in a single row in css?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to Create a CSS style that displays 3 elements in a single row, but the second elements should start after the first element ends, third element starts after 2nd element ends.

It must be responsive.
Thanks.

[image: Please see the image]

Comment: What have you done until now please show us some of your work first

Comment: Take a look at css “inline”  element layout  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating some custom quote symbols, just use `quotes` css and `::before` `::after` pseudo elements to customize them:

```css
q {
  quotes: "<" ">";
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

q::before {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

q::after {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

q::before, q::after {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur quisquam nam perspiciatis obcaecati aspernatur quo nostrum culpa! Earum beatae ducimus architecto amet totam debitis sint cupiditate consequatur sapiente, sit nihil. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur quisquam nam perspiciatis obcaecati aspernatur quo nostrum culpa! Earum beatae ducimus architecto amet totam debitis sint cupiditate consequatur sapiente, sit nihil.</q>
```

Comment: Hi bro, it's working fine...but, please look in to left side of text...

Comment: @sadiquekp Adjust it accordingly, try it now. You can adjust all the numbers to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without using css

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">@</a>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd<br>fdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
  <a href="#">@</a></div>
```

Comment: look at that picture... the text should be in center of first and last element